# Create a circle or a disk with antialiasing for retina display

Tags: ios, swift, core-graphics

I have creating a circle using `CGContextFillEllipseInRect` from `CoreGraphic`.

I'm using this circle (which is actually a disk) to replace the `thumbImage` of an `UISlider`. The antialiasing is applied by default.

But the result on my iPhone 6 is clearly not good. I can clearly see the pixels ,not as much as with the antialiasing off, but way more than the pixels of a normal UISlider.

Maybe I'm doing something wrong. So my question is, is there a way to get programmatically the same nice disk than the one used by default for an UISlider?

**EDIT:**

Here is how I create the disk:

```
class func drawDisk(rgbValue:UInt32, rectForDisk: CGRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0)) -> UIImage {
    let color = uicolorFromHex(rgbValue)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rectForDisk.size)
    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
    CGContextFillEllipseInRect(context, rectForDisk)

    let rectForCircle = CGRectMake(0.5, 0.5, rectForDisk.size.width - 1, rectForDisk.size.height - 1)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 1.0)
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context,
            UIColor.blackColor().CGColor)
    CGContextAddEllipseInRect(context, rectForCircle)
    CGContextStrokePath(context)

    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return image
}
```

Comment: How are you creating the image context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you are creating a non-retina graphics context when using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext`, as mentioned in the documentation:

> This function is equivalent to calling the `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` function with the opaque parameter set to `NO` and a scale factor of `1.0`.

Instead you should be using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` to create your image context. You can keep passing `NO` for the opaque parameter if you want an image that supports transparency (same as what you are implicitly doing now).

In most cases you can pass `0.0` for the scale factor. This sets the scale factor to that of the device's main screen. Again, as mentioned in the documentation:

> If you specify a value of `0.0`, the scale factor is set to the scale factor of the device’s main screen.

---

So, in short, you should create your image context like this:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rectForDisk.size, false, 0.0) // false for Swift
```

Comment: Much better indeed! Thanks a lot!